# Can "pragmatic" be used as a noun, e.g. "He was a pragmatic"?

Tags: word-usage

Like "He was a romantic."

I'm aware of the word *pragmatist*, but the word *pragmatic* sounds better in my application.

Comment: Wrong forum. Could someone with the appropriate system priv move this question to the correct forum, whatever that is?

Comment: @BlessedGeek - Could you explain, please? I thought this appropriately fell under [grammar](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: -- ELU vs ELL --

Comment: @BlessedGeek - I am a native speaker, though. (Despite my name, I was born in the U.S.) Not to say ELL is only for non-native speakers, but I think I'm asking on a higher level than simply learning, I think. I _know_ that _pragmatist_ is the correct word. I'm asking if _a pragmatic_ might be valid too, because in a presentation I'm writing, I dislike how "the _idealist_ and the _pragmatist_" sounds (completely subjective, but it sounds a bit too black-and-white / dichotomous to me), and I would like it if I could say "...and the pragmatic."

Comment: ELL is not for *non-native* speakers only. BTW, I did not notice your name. Now I do.

Comment: @BlessedGeek... Is that... your only counterargument? Because I addressed this, if you read my third sentence.

Comment: I voted to close this question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233635/how-do-i-punctuate-the-following-sentence. Should I pay attn to the name before I vote to close from now on?

Comment: @BlessedGeek - Sorry, I think I just don't understand you. My point wasn't about my name—I was just clarifying in case my name had something to do with an assumption that I'm not a native speaker. I gave a reason as to why I felt my question was more appropriate on ELU than ELL. Maybe it's a bad question in general, and that's fine to say, but really, I was only trying to address your arguments here, and I don't understand your counterarguments. Let's just let a mod handle this.

Comment: @BlessedGeek `English Language Learners Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for speakers of other languages learning English. ` http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour While they do accept questions from people who are native speakers that is not what it says on the tin.

Comment: Does ELL first ask the questioner "are you native-speaker or not" before opening the gate to allow the questioner to ask a question? If a purporting "native speaker" asks basic grammatical or vocab questions that should be asked at ELL, are they to ask the question at ELU just because they confess to being "native speakers" ???

Comment: @BlessedGeek What ELL do is irrelevant, what their 'mission statement' says is all that matters. ELL is not a site for questions that don't come from _linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts_. http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/811/6494

Comment: Therefore, in the future, you would want none of us here to vote out-of-topic when a questioner asks basic grammatical / vocab questions? And you would prefer to prevent us from recommending that they ask that question in ELL. Also you would want us to first ask "are you native-speaker" before voting to close a question ???

Comment: BTW, that is why I used "whatever", noticed ? Because the last time, I recommended a question being in the wrong forum - someone corrected me by saying that I should have sent the questioner to ELL. From now on, I will revert to just recommending that such questions are in the "wrong forum", without adding that it should've been asked at whichever forum. So many contradicting opinions that try to be "authoritative".

Comment: +Frank, pls respond, or correct yourself.

Comment: @BlessedGeek  I have nothing to correct myself about, the ELL 'mission statement' and the ELL-meta answer are not my creations.

Comment: Forget about ELL. What I meant is - Do we or do we not direct someone to ELL, when someone asks a basic English vocab/grammar question. If you think we should not, would you kindly write the same comment to every comment/vote that had sent a question to ELL?

Comment: @BlessedGeek That is a question that should probably be asked in meta, then you won't just get my opinion on the matter.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to request you to write the same opinion to every comment in ELU that sends a question to the ELL. Not about other's opinion.

Answer (score 2):

According to the standards of English, the answer is NO!

A similar discussion is here

http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1802417

There has been an archaic usage of pragmatic as a NOUN

> 1. PRAGMATIC: [noun (Archaic)]
>
>    A person given to intruding in other
>      people's affairs:

**SOURCES:**

- http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pragmatic
- http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pragmaticality

(A detailed explanation with examples is given in the references above)

Another way where Pragmatic can be used as a noun is

> 2. PRAGMATIC:[noun] -
>
> An imperial decree that becomes part of the
>    fundamental law of the land

In both the cases, pragmatic as a noun, can't be used in the current context that you'd want to. You must only use it as an adjective as in 'pragmatic'. If you really want to use it as a noun, then you must go with 'pragmatist'.

```
The correct usage is:

1. [ADJECTIVE] "He was a pragmatic man".

2. [NOUN] "Sally is a pragmatist".
```

SOURCE: http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/pragmatist

Answer (score 1):

Good question, Andrew. In my humble opinion, you are free to use the language however you choose - *within reason* - and referring to someone as a "pragmatic" isn't unreasonable (as your example, "*romantic*," demonstrates) nor is it likely to be misunderstood, which should *really* be your guiding concern. Feel free to experiment with the language, it's *yours* after all.  ;-)